# Side menu Ionic is not showing the title / buttons

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I just started an Ionic App and I got a problem with the `SideMenu` component.

Here's the code that I have now:

**Index:**

```
<body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

**Menu:**

```
<ion-side-menus>
    <ion-side-menu side="left">
        <header class="bar bar-header bar-stable">
            <h1 class="title">Menu</h1>
        </header>
        <ion-content class="has-header">
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/menu/categories">
                    Categories
                </ion-item>                 
                <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/menu/another">
                    Another
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>

    <ion-pane ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
            <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear"><i class="icon ion-chevron-left"></i> Back</ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view name="menuContent" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
        <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
            <button menu-toggle="right" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-pane>
</ion-side-menus>
```

**Child view:**

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-nav-title>Categories></ion-nav-title> <!-- nothing shows -->
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left"><!-- nothing shows -->
        <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-content class="has-header">
      ...
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Everything is working fine, except the title of "child" views and the `nav-buttons`. I read the docs and find some examples and my code above seems really fine.

Any help would be appreciated.